# Why does my Javascript code runs and disappear immediately

Tags: javascript, html, function, return

I wrote the codes below to display the user's names when the user enter their name. But the name will appear and disappear immediately. What is wrong?

html codes

```
<div>
   <p id="names"></p>
</div>

<form method = "get" action = "">
   Enter first name: <input type = "text" id = "firstName"/>
   Enter last name: <input type = "text" id = "lastName"/>
   <input type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = "return firstName_lastName();"/>
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
function firstName_lastName() {
   var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
   var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
   var names = document.getElementById('names');

  if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
   alert('Please fill in all the fields');
   return false; 
  } else {
    names.innerHTML = firstName + " " + lastName; 
   return true; 
}
```

The code works but the names appear and disappear immediately.

Edit: The code runs but when the submit button is clicked, the entered first and last names appear on the browser and disappear immediately.
The alert also works perfectly when any or both of the fields are not filled.

Comment: I have edited the post and adjusted the bracelet

Comment: By default, form submission reloads the page. To prevent that, use `event.preventDefault()`. Make sure that the event handler function receives the `event` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submit button is basically submitting form to server and reloading page when clicked but if you want to validate before submit you can use `preventDefault` to stop page reload
see example below

```js
function firstName_lastName(event) {
    event.preventDefault() // to stop submit
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var names = document.getElementById('names');

    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
        alert('Please fill in all the fields');
    }
    names.innerText = `${firstName} ${lastName}` 
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p id="names"></p>
</div>

<form method = "get" action = "">
   Enter first name: <input type = "text" id = "firstName"/>
   Enter last name: <input type = "text" id = "lastName"/>
   <input type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = " firstName_lastName(event);"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Amir Rahman and Yousaf. The preventDefault event worked. But with the preventDefault, will the form be able to submit if there is backend? Also, what if I want the name to remain there even after reloading?

Comment: use ajax for submission without page reload thats the preferred way since no one likes page reload for a form submission

Comment: Can you help me with the ajax code for submission without page reload.

Comment: there are libraries like jquery , axios to do ajax operations doing it all from scratch is a bit lengthy i would suggest to use jquery $.post method to submit form to server it is the most simple and userfriendly and if you dont like to use libraries you can use fetch take a look at this for fetch example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: if this answer resolves your problem consider accepting it

Answer (score 2):

```
function firstName_lastName(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // to stop submit
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var names = document.getElementById('names');

    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
        alert('Please fill in all the fields');
    }
    names.innerText = `${firstName} ${lastName}` 
}
```

The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when:

Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL
Note: Not all events are cancelable. Use the cancelable property to find out if an event is cancelable.

Note: The preventDefault() method does not prevent further propagation of an event through the DOM. Use the stopPropagation() method to handle this.